# Is getRemote().sendString(msg, new WriteCallback() {..}) stable?

Tags: java, asynchronous, websocket, jetty

I have

```
class MyWebSocket extends WebSocketAdapter
```

I need to send text1, text2 and text3 to websocket client using:

```
getRemote().sendString(text, new WriteCallback() {...})
```

This call is async, so I expect that job is done in different threads from jetty's pool.

My question is:

Can I be sure that on the client the sequence will be the same: text1, text2 and text3?

If yes, please add a link to official documentation if any.

---

Update:
In the documentation for [RemoteEndpoint](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.12.v20160915/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendString-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WriteCallback-) one can read:

```
void sendString(String text)
         throws IOException
```

> Send a text message, blocking until all bytes of the message has been
>   transmitted.

and

```
void sendString(String text,
                WriteCallback callback)
```

> Initiates the asynchronous transmission of a text message. This method
>   may return before the message is transmitted. Developers may provide a
>   callback to be notified when the message has been transmitted or
>   resulted in an error.

So, in case of sendString with callback, how it can be asynchronous if the callback is called in the same thread?

Also, what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: I don't see a remark for the async method that the callback is invoked (synchronously) from the same thread. I would estimate it's called from another thread, which processes the outgoing frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That call simply queues the outgoing text for the WebSocket endpoint.

Then, when the NIO layers reports that a Write is possible, the queued message is converted to frames, passed through the WebSocket extensions, masked (if sent from a client), then written to the socket.

Once the entire buffer for that frame is written to the socket, the WriteCallback is triggered.

None of this is on a different thread.

There is only 1 thread handling write, and it just processes messages from the queue.

Comment: Thanks! Am I right: my thread is blocked till "the NIO layers reports that a Write is possible"?

Comment: There is a separate thread handling read, and notification to your Endpoint.  The blocked thread isn't from the write/NIO, but probably the queuing.  Its not infinite, and after a while (due to memory pressures) the enqueue blocks.